# How to transform points from a plane to a different plane?

Tags: geometry, 3d, isometry, rigid-transformation

I have a plane $\Pi_1$ expressed as $ax+by+cy+d=0$ and a different plane $\Pi_2$ expressed as $ex+fy+gz+h=0$.

I am looking for a transformation which rigidly brings points lying on $\Pi_1$ to points lying on $\Pi_2$,  i.e. the 2D distance between any two given points on $\Pi_1$ must remain the same when the points are mapped to $\Pi_2$.

I know that a point $P_1=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$, which is lying on $\Pi_1$, is mapped by the transformation to $P_2=(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ which lies on $\Pi_2$, is this enough to compute the transformation?

How can I compute it?

Is it an homography?

Comment: A distance-preserving map is known as an isometry.

Comment: @TheoBendit thank you, I have updated the tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A distance-preserving map is known as an isometry. Fix $x_0 \in \Pi_1$ and $y_0 \in \Pi_2$. To find an isometry between $\Pi_1$ and $\Pi_2$, mapping $x_0$ to $y_0$, you can follow the following steps:

1. Consider the planes $\Pi'_1$ and $\Pi'_2$ defined by respectively translating $\Pi_1$ by $-x_0$ and $\Pi_2$ by $y_0$ so that they both go through the origin. Equivalently, they are defined by replacing $d$ and $h$ by $0$. Such planes are vector subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$.
2. Find orthonormal bases for $\Pi'_1$ and $\Pi'_2$. For each plane, this can be done by finding two non-parallel vectors in the plane and applying the Gram-Schmidt procedure.
3. Define a linear transformation $T : \Pi_1' \to \Pi_2'$ defined by mapping one orthonormal basis to the other. Such a map will necessarily be an isometry.
4. The affine map $x \mapsto y_0 + T(x - x_0)$ will an isometry from $\Pi_1$ to $\Pi_2$, mapping $x_0$ to $y_0$.

In fact, this method will generate all possible isometries between these planes, as the Mazur-Ulam theorem implies.

EDIT: $T$ is a linear transformation between two-dimensional spaces $\Pi'_1$ and $\Pi'_2$. Given the two orthonormal bases for $\Pi'_1$ and $\Pi'_2$ found in step 2, the matrix for the transformation, from one orthonormal basis to the other, is the identity matrix. That is, the transformation maps a coordinate vector in one basis to exactly the same coordinate vector in the other basis.

It is possible (and probably easier computationally) to extend $T$ to a linear isometry $S : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$, which will have a *standard* matrix.

To do this, extend the bases for $\Pi'_1$ and $\Pi'_2$ to bases for $\mathbb{R}^3$, then apply Gram-Schmidt. The result should be two orthonormal bases for $\mathbb{R}^3$. Again, define a linear map that maps one basis to the other. The result is a linear isometry that is the same as $T$ when restricted to $\Pi'_1$.

Let's go through an example. Suppose $\Pi_1$ is the plane defined by the equation $x + 2z + 3 = 0$ and $\Pi_2$ is the plane defined by $-x + 3y + z - 4 = 0$. In particular, fix points $x_0 = (-1, -1, -1) \in \Pi_1$ and $y_0 = (4, 0, 0) \in \Pi_2$.

Step 1:
\begin{align*}
\Pi_1' &= \lbrace (x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x + 2z = 0 \rbrace \\
\Pi_2' &= \lbrace (x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : -x + 3y + z = 0 \rbrace \\
\end{align*}

Step 2: We find arbitrary, non-parallel vectors in $\Pi_1'$ and $\Pi_2'$. I'm going to take $(-2, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0) \in \Pi_1'$ and $(3, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1) \in \Pi_2'$. Since we also want to find $S$, we need one more vector each, that doesn't lie in the respective planes. For both, I'm going to choose $(1, 0, 0) \notin \Pi_1' \cup \Pi_2'$. We therefore start with (not orthonormal) bases:
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{B}_1 &= ((-2, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0)) \\
\mathcal{B}_2 &= ((3, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0)).
\end{align*}
We need to apply the Gram-Schmidt procedure to each of these bases. For $\mathcal{B}_1$, we have
\begin{align*}
u_1 &= \frac{(-2, 0, 1)}{\|(-2, 0, 1)\|} = \left(\frac{-2}{\sqrt{5}}, 0, \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right) \\
u_2 &= \frac{(0, 1, 0) - ((0, 1, 0) \cdot u_1)u_1}{\|(0, 1, 0) - ((0, 1, 0) \cdot u_1)u_1\|} = (0, 1, 0) \\
u_3 &= \frac{(1, 0, 0) - ((1, 0, 0) \cdot u_1)u_1 - ((1, 0, 0) \cdot u_2)u_2}{\|(1, 0, 0) - ((1, 0, 0) \cdot u_1)u_1 - ((1, 0, 0) \cdot u_2)u_2\|} = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}, 0, \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\right)
\end{align*}
So, we get an orthonormal basis
$$\mathcal{E}_1 = \left(\left(\frac{-2}{\sqrt{5}}, 0, \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right), (0, 1, 0), \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}, 0, \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\right)\right).$$
Similarly, using $\mathcal{B}_2$, we obtain
$$\mathcal{E}_2 = \left(\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}, 0\right), \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{110}}, \frac{-3}{\sqrt{110}}, \frac{10}{\sqrt{110}}\right), \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{11}}, \frac{-3}{\sqrt{11}}, \frac{-1}{\sqrt{11}}\right)\right).$$
If we remove the last vector in $\mathcal{E}_1$ and $\mathcal{E}_2$, then we obtain orthonormal bases for $\Pi'_1$ and $\Pi'_2$ respectively.

Step 3: We define $S$ to be a linear transformation that maps
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{-2}{\sqrt{5}}, 0, \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right) &\mapsto \left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}, 0\right) \\
(0, 1, 0) &\mapsto \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{110}}, \frac{-3}{\sqrt{110}}, \frac{10}{\sqrt{110}}\right) \\
\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}, 0, \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\right) &\mapsto \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{11}}, \frac{-3}{\sqrt{11}}, \frac{-1}{\sqrt{11}}\right).
\end{align*}
To compute the standard matrix, we compute the image of the standard basis vectors. For example, we have
\begin{align*}(1, 0, 0) &= \left((1, 0, 0) \cdot \left(\frac{-2}{\sqrt{5}}, 0, \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right)\right)\left(\frac{-2}{\sqrt{5}}, 0, \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right) \\
&+ ((1, 0, 0) \cdot (0, 1, 0))(0, 1, 0) \\
&+ \left((1, 0, 0) \cdot \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}, 0, \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\right)\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}, 0, \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\right) \\
&= \frac{-2}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{-2}{\sqrt{5}}, 0, \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right) + 0(0, 1, 0) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}, 0, \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\right) \\
&\mapsto \frac{-2}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}, 0\right) + 0\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{110}}, \frac{-3}{\sqrt{110}}, \frac{10}{\sqrt{110}}\right) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{11}}, \frac{-3}{\sqrt{11}}, \frac{-1}{\sqrt{11}}\right) \\
&= \left(\frac{-33\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{55}}{55}, \frac{-11\sqrt{2} - 3\sqrt{55}}{55}, \frac{-\sqrt{55}}{55}\right).
\end{align*}
We have already
$$(0, 1, 0) \mapsto \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{110}}, \frac{-3}{\sqrt{110}}, \frac{10}{\sqrt{110}}\right)$$
Using similar methods, we finally have,
$$(0, 0, 1) \mapsto \left(\frac{33\sqrt{2}-4\sqrt{55}}{110}, \frac{11\sqrt{2}-6\sqrt{55}}{110}, \frac{4\sqrt{55}}{110}\right).$$
This gives us the standard matrix for $S$:
$$\mathcal{M}(S) = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{-33\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{55}}{55} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{110}} & \frac{33\sqrt{2} - 4\sqrt{55}}{110} \\
\frac{-11\sqrt{2} - 3\sqrt{55}}{55} & \frac{-3}{\sqrt{110}} & \frac{-11\sqrt{2} - 6\sqrt{55}}{110} \\
\frac{-\sqrt{55}}{55} & \frac{10}{\sqrt{110}} & \frac{4\sqrt{55}}{110}
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Step 4: We define the isometry, mapping $x_0$ to $y_0$ by
$$\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{-33\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{55}}{55} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{110}} & \frac{33\sqrt{2} - 4\sqrt{55}}{110} \\
\frac{-11\sqrt{2} - 3\sqrt{55}}{55} & \frac{-3}{\sqrt{110}} & \frac{-11\sqrt{2} - 6\sqrt{55}}{110} \\
\frac{-\sqrt{55}}{55} & \frac{10}{\sqrt{110}} & \frac{4\sqrt{55}}{110}
\end{pmatrix}\left(\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ -1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}\right) + \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Is $T$ a $3\times3$ matrix?

Comment: How many vectors are there in an orthonormal basis for $\Pi_1$ (or $\Pi_2$)?

Comment: @AlessandroJacopson I've made extensive edits.

Answer (score 1):

[Theo Bendit’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2944635/265466) explains in excruciating detail how to construct all possible isometries between the two planes. This one specifically addresses one of the questions that you ask: “Is this enough to compute the transformation?”

The short answer is no. Using homogeneous coordinates, an isometry of $\mathbb R^3$ can be represented by a $4\times4$ matrix of the form $$M = \left[\begin{array}{c|c}R & \mathbf t \\ \hline \mathbf 0^T & 1\end{array}\right],$$ where the $3\times3$ submatrix $R$ is orthogonal, i.e., $R^TR = RR^T=I$. Points are transformed by multiplying their homogeneous coordinate vectors by $M$, while planes, which are represented by covariant vectors, are transformed via multiplication by the inverse transpose of $M$, $$M^{-T} = \left[\begin{array}{c|c} R & \mathbf 0 \\ \hline  -\mathbf t^T R & 1\end{array}\right].$$

W.l.o.g. we can assume that $\Pi_2$ is the $x$-$y$ plane and we’ll further assume that the normal $\mathbf n_1 = (a,b,c)$ of $\Pi_1$ is a unit vector. The requirement that this normal be mapped onto the $z$-axis determines the third row of $R$ up to a choice of sign. In fact, it is $\pm\mathbf n^T$. We can then choose any unit vector orthogonal to $\mathbf n$ for one of the other rows of $R$, which determines the remaining row, again up to sign. Once we’ve fixed $R$, the point pair $P_1$ and $P_2$ determines the translation component $\mathbf t$ of $M$. Thus, with the given constraints, three degrees of freedom remain.

Comment: I love the *excruciating detail* :-)